# TCL Expect script embedding python variable

Tags: python, expect

Below is my python function wherein I need to embed the python variable *file_search* inside the **expect** script right after the **ls** -**ltr** command. The quotes are giving me nightmare. Any easy way to tackle these quotes and make it more understandable?

```
def checkLatencyTime(file_search, corr_check = False, ip = None, passwd = None):
    cmdStr = ""
    return_code = 3
    if ip and passwd:
        for x in range(len(ip)):
            cmd ="/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh " + ip[x] + " \"/usr/bin/expect -c \'\\\'\'spawn ls -ltr; expect \\\"continue connecting (yes/no)?\\\" { send yes\r}; expect \\\"password: \\\" { send \\\""+passwd[x]+"\r\\\"};interact\'\\\'\'\" ; expect \\\"~]#\\\" { send echo -\r}; expect \"password: \" { send \""+passwd[x]+"\r\"};expect \"~]#\" { send echo -\r};expect \"continue connecting (yes/no)?\" { send yes\r};interact'"
```

Here a section of code is given, I am trying to establish connection with a remote server and execute a lengthy pipeline command (not really just **ls** as given here) on that server using **expect**, retrieve the output and processing it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't even follow what you're trying to do. You're using expect to ssh to A and on the remote server, use expect to... do "ls"???? Why do you think you need to run expect on the remote server?

My Python is rusty, but perhaps:

```py
cmd = [
    '/usr/bin/expect', 
    '-c', 
    '''
        spawn ssh {0} ls -ltr {1}
        expect {
            "continue connecting" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
            "assword:"
        }
        send "{2}\r"
        expect eof
    '''.format(ip[x], file_search", passwd[x])
]
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion however, I get KeyError at the innermost `expect {}` due to braces

Comment: I was wondering about that while I was writing. I'm sure Python gives you other ways to build a string.